# Kubernetes system container "pause" doesn't get proper port mappings

Tags: kubernetes

I am testing out a kubernetes 1.1.7 setup (on AWS). This has been installed following standard procedures (http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/getting-started-guides/aws.html) and it's all working fine.

I have tried to fireup the most simple replication controller of a pod with two containers (because I wanted to play around multi-container pods, which are not the norm but still something that could be done). This is the RC:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test
  labels:
    app: web
spec:
  containers:
    - name: "80"
      image: "jonlangemak/docker:web_container_80"
      ports:
        - containerPort: 80
    - name: "8080"
      image: "jonlangemak/docker:web_container_8080"
      ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

I was expecting this to generate 2 application containers as well as a system container "pause" which would hold the two port mappings (80 and 8080).

However, if I go on the landing host and I do a docker ps this is what I see:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                 COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
2a15f633fff9        jonlangemak/docker:web_container_8080                 "/usr/bin/supervisor   23 seconds ago      Up 22 seconds                           k8s_8080.cf4f64ab_test_default_1dc9f591-d976-11e5-88b3-06da266e4957_6e389304                                                                                
0ff0b6cdd4ae        jonlangemak/docker:web_container_80                   "/usr/bin/supervisor   23 seconds ago      Up 23 seconds                           k8s_80.b7c46373_test_default_1dc9f591-d976-11e5-88b3-06da266e4957_90173279                                                                                  
84e3d7ea12c9        gcr.io/google_containers/pause:0.8.0                  "/pause"               23 seconds ago      Up 23 seconds                           k8s_POD.c16231a_test_default_1dc9f591-d976-11e5-88b3-06da266e4957_78c2a5e9
```

Interestingly, everything works fine and I can curl the pod IP for both port 80 and port 8080 and I get what I am expecting to get BUT the fact that I don't see the proper port mappings on the "pause" container leaves me a bit "uh? why?".

Thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There won't be any port mapping unless you set the HostPort property on the corresponding `port`.

Instead of doing that, you should use a Service to expose your application. This abstraction will give your application a single IP adress and act as a local load balancer within your cluster.

You can read more about Kubernetes `service` resource in the official [Kubernetes user documentation](http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/user-guide/services.html)

Comment: thanks @Antoine I am (somewhat) familiar with the notion of `service` and I have that working as well (I was just missing that the port mapping is shown when the mapping is explicitly set in the yaml). I have added the `hostPort` value and now it shows up. Thanks!